# How to update java runtime in android studio

Tags: java, android

I am facing this error and all my project code is in red. How can i solve this. I tried to download new version of JRE but can not solve. How can i upgrade?

> IDE's Java runtime (1.8u92), which may cause instability. Update to version 1.8.0u144 or higher.

Comment: probably you need not JRE, but JDK

Comment: I also updated it, it is not solving the problem

Comment: I'm assuming your `PATH` is now well setup

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your tips guys, I had to download and install the latest version of jdk then go to Environment Variables in my computer settings and update the JAVA_HOME path from the old one to the new java installed.

Then restart my computer and run Android Studio. Thats how I solved it. Everything is fine now thank you guys for some tips.